# error with git when checking out

Tags: git, github

I am getting the following error when doing a checkout:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    Examples/RKTwitter/RKTwitter.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
    RestKit.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

What should I do? Remove it? If I want to move it, don't know where to move it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove it. It's just Xcode 4's workspace data file that will get recreated once you reopen the project in Xcode 4 again. Warning also says that that file was created on the other end from where you're doing the pull.

So I'm suggest you to add this file to `.gitignore` list and do `git rm` on that file where it was added in the git repo.

Comment: I tried to do a git rm Examples/RKTwitter/RKTwitter.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata but it fails... why is this?

Comment: because your side wasn't the one that added this file to the git repo.

Comment: so?? what should I do? how do I remove it

Comment: remove that file by hand via terminal. Then do the branch switch.

Comment: You should really take Elimantas' suggestion and add these types of files to your `.gitignore`.